# Returning variable outside function

Tags: python, function, return

Why is `x` not defined outside the function? Is `return x` placed wrong?

```
def find():
```

x
            else:

```
find()
```

Comment: You are breaking before you are returning, and should your conditional statement evaluate to false you aren't returning at all.

Comment: `break` immediately exits the loop, so the statement after it is never executed.

Comment: please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Comment: If you don't explicitly `return`, Python returns `None`

Answer (score 6):

Put `return x` outside the loop:

```
def find(): 
    data=file('file.dat')
    x=0
    for line in data:
        if 'metaend' in line:
            break
        else:
            x+=1
    return x
```

To get the value of `x`, you use the return value of the function:

```
count = find()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function never returns anything. Check this, with some added error handling for no end of metadata detection

```
def find(): 
    data=file('file.dat')
    x=0
    for line in data:
        if 'metaend' in line:
            return x

        x += 1
    raise Exception('heeey no end of metadata')
```

By the way, python has a very nice function for a counter in a loop:

```
def find(): 
    data=file('file.dat')

    for counter, line in enumerate(data):
        if 'metaend' in line:
            return counter

    raise Exception('heeey no end of metadata')
```